# maven - how to exclude an entire module on from war

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

I have the following Maven project structure:

- ProjectA

  - `sub-projectB` <- jar
  - `sub-projectC` <- war
  - `sub-projectD` <- war

`sub-projectC` and `sub-projectD` need to have `sub-projectB` as a dependency. But the war built by `sub-projectC` and `sub-projectD` should not include the dependencies of `sub-projectB`. The jar will be included separately later in the classpath (this is because `sub-projectB` is large jar >100MB and packaging it with the war will be very expensive both in terms of size and time it takes to copy the war from one location to another during deployment).

How do I exclude the dependencies of `sub-projectB` from the war package of `sub-projectC` and `sub-projectD`?

One way to do it is to exclude the list of jars in the `maven-war-plugin`. But we have to specify each and every jar names or use wild-card. We can not exclude a sub-module dependencies directly. Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what the scope [`provided`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) is for. Each dependency with this scope will be used at compile-time but it will not be included in the final war (because it is *provided* by the run-time container).

As such, the dependency to `sub-projectB` should be, in `sub-projectC` and `sub-projectD` pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>sub-projectB</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```